# In Snowflake, will granting ownership on a table to a role allow the role to Select from that table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

I am trying to understand the ownership privilege better. I think the question is clear enough. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

From [Table Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#table-privileges):

> OWNERSHIP
>
> **Grants full control over the table.** Required to alter most properties a table, with the exception of reclustering. Only a single role can hold this privilege on a specific object at a time.